# Are SVN repo versions copies or just references?

Tags: svn, repository-design

This may be a very elementary question, but I can't find an answer anywhere.  I'm new to SVN and trying to determine the best configuration for my repo for a new project.  This project is essentially two main parts: code and data.  The code is small memory-wise, but it depends on the data, which is about 400 MB altogether.

Not totally understanding how SVN works, if I keep both parts together in the repo, will the 400 MB of data get completely copied with every new version?  Or does SVN only keep some kind of reference to unchanged pieces?  If it's the former, then I should keep the data separate from the code in the repo, correct?  What I do not want is for the 400 MB to get copied each time SVN saves a new version.  I'll run out of network space very quickly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How exactly does subversion store files in the repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332833/how-exactly-does-subversion-store-files-in-the-repository)

Comment: Question title doesn't correlate with body, will you fix it?

Comment: @LazyBadger: Title edited to reflect the real question.  Sorry.

Comment: @StephenKennedy: Not exactly a duplicate.  My question was even more elementary than that. But that posting did answer my question.  Thanks!