# Are my files physically stored in Subversion Repository folder?

Tags: svn, version-control, repository

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How exactly does subversion store files in the repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332833/how-exactly-does-subversion-store-files-in-the-repository)

I have imported a fresh new project into my Subversion repository which is of 36MB, but after I imported my project, I checked the Repository folder and I see that the Repository folder just increased by 6MB. So, I am wondering, where actually my project files are saved ?

Environment: Windows 7, Client : Tortoise Subversion, Visual Studio Plugin : Visual Subversion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/127692/svn-performance-after-many-revisions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332833/how-exactly-does-subversion-store-files-in-the-repository

Answer (score 3):

The files that you import into the Subversion repository are automatically compressed.

Answer (score 2):

By default, Subversion store all the project information in a `BerkeleyDB` database system.

So they are inside a DB which means compression, normalization and whatnot...

Comment: Nowadays Subversion by default uses its own custom storage format (FSFS), not BerkeleyDB.